Comparing probability of two events with different durations
So let us say two people, A and B, are fighting.
A has a 15% chance to stun B for 2 turns. B has a 25% chance to stun A for 1 turn. Who gets stunned more over a large no of rounds?
Here is how the fighting goes:
This is a turn-based battle and A goes first each round.
Round begins:

A attacks B. Can stun with chance 15%. If he succeeds, B will remain stunned for two rounds.
Next, B attacks. He will stun with chance 25%. however, he can only manage to stun for 1 round at a time.

Note: A can refresh his stun on consecutive rounds.
A few example iterations:

Round 1: A and B are fine. A does nothing. B does nothing.
Round 2: A and B are fine. A does nothing. B stuns.
Round 3: A stunned, B is fine. B does nothing.
Round 4: A recovers. A and B are fine. A stuns. B cannot do anything.
Round 5: A fine, B stunned. A does nothing. B is stunned.
Round 6: A fine, B stunned. A does nothing. Now, B recovers. B does nothing.

Another example:

Round 1: A and B are fine. A stuns. B cannot do anything.
Round 2: A fine, B stunned. A stuns again refreshing the stun. B is stunned.
Round 3: A fine, B stunned. A does nothing. B is stunned. Now, B recovers.
Round 4: A and B are fine. A does nothing. B stuns.
Round 5: A stunned, B is fine. A does nothing. B does nothing.
Round 6: A recovers, B fine. A does nothing. B does nothing.

So the question is, who is stunned for more rounds when fighting over many rounds? How will this change if B starts first each round?
Related problem: the chances are $p$ and $q$ respectively and they occur for $m$ and $n$ rounds.

Please edit to include your efforts.  And for clarity.  I suggest working it out completely for, say, $5$ rounds...that should clarify the rules.

@lulu I added more details. Hopefully it is clear now.

I am rather stunned by the description of the game after first read !

@trueblueanil it is part of a RPG game

Can both get stunned in a round ?

No. If a player is stunned, they won't be able to act.
